# LINQ to XML get value from anywhere using hierarchy patterns

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to parse a poorly formatted xml document. There are some patterns in the xml such as for eg. I want to get the value of a node `Name` that has parent `MyParentNode`. Then later down, there is another node `Name` that I'd like to get under `Farm`. For eg.

```
<Node>
    <MyParentNode>
         <Name>LOL</Name>
         <RandomNode>
              <Farms>
                   <Farm>
                       <Name>MyFarmName</Name>
                   </Farm>
                   <Farm>
                       <Name>MyFarmName2</Name>
                   </Farm>
              </Farms>
         </RandomNode>
    </MyParentNode>
</Node>
```

So from this, I'd like to extract an array that looks like this:

```
public class SomeClass{
     public string ParentName {get; set;} // MyParentNode->Name
     public string Name {get; set;} //RandomNode->Farms->Farm->Name
}
```

I basically want to flatten this xml into an array of:

```
List<SomeClass> list = FlattenXml();
list[0]; //ParentName = LOL, Name = MyFarmName
list[1]; //ParentName = LOL, Name = MyFarmName2
```

The problem is that some of these data are deep down in the hierarchy and sometimes they are random. But they can be found from the pattern of the Parent node and child node. Could someone show me the code to solve the above problem please?

Answer (score 0):

This works on the XML snippet you have posted.

```
var result = from node in doc.Descendants("MyParentNode")
             select new
             {
                 ParentName = node.Descendants("Name").First().Value,
                 FarmList = from farm in node.Descendants("Farm")
                            select farm.Element("Name").Value
             };

var flattened = result.SelectMany(a => a.FarmList,
    (a, b) => new SomeClass { ParentName = a.ParentName, Name = b });
```

Result:

```
ParentName  Name
LOL         MyFarmName
LOL         MyFarmName2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class SomeClass
        {
            public string ParentName { get; set; } // MyParentNode->Name
            public List<string> Name { get; set; } //RandomNode->Farms->Farm->Name
        }
        static List<SomeClass> FlattenXml(XElement source)
        {
            List<SomeClass> result;

            result = (from item in source.Elements()
                      select new SomeClass()
                      {
                          ParentName = item.Element("Name").ToString(),
                          Name = (from i in item.Descendants("Farm")
                                      select i.Element("Name").Value).ToList()


                      }).ToList();

            return result;
        }
```